# unable to get the input id that triggered the event using event.target.id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code right here for getting the id of a clicked input element:

```
jQuery(event.target.id).change(function(){

if(event.target.id===null)
    {

    }
else
    {   
    alert(event.target.id);
    }
});
```

for example: i have a dynamically generated textbox. Upon clicking it using the code above, it returns the id.

However when I click a dropdown list input, it returns null, but when inspecting the element, the id is there. It still goes to the else block.

I am using this event for fields that were dynamically generated.

What might be wrong?

Sorry if it seems noobish I am new on jQuery.

Comment: this type of structure of event is followed in `angular js`. For normal jquery, you can use `this` object and get the `id` inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On select elements you need to listen to the change event, not the click event:

```
$('select').change(function() {
  var selectId = $(this).attr('id');
  var optionId = $(this).find(":selected").attr('id');
  alert('select id:' + selectId);
  alert('option id: ' + optionId);
});
```

**UPDATE**
Usually in a select element you would be looking for the option value. This is how you would do that:

```
$('#selectId').change(function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).find(":selected").val()
  alert(optionValue);
});
```

Comment: Maybe you misunderstood my post,I am using the event.target.id because the list that I want to get the id from is a dynamically generated field, not like those defined fields that I automatically know the ID of. I can't use #selectId.

Comment: Is the id attribute on the select element or the option elements?

Comment: I am still testing the code above for the select element. If i find solution for the select element, i would implement it on option elements.

Comment: I've updated my answer so you now have the selected option id available and the original select id available.

Comment: your code works perfect! thanks. Will use the select tag instead of the event.target.id.

Comment: var optionId = $(this).find(":selected").attr('id'); returns undefined even though I have options to select from.

Comment: Is it a multi option select? Could you add some html to your question?

Comment: from the code you provided above, 
var optionValue = $(this).find(":selected").val()

 this works. I might as well use this.

Answer (score 0):

Try access original target

```
 var originalElement = event.srcElement || event.originalTarget;
 console.log(originalElement.id)
```